# Flex Project Include SWFAddress.js

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, swfaddress

Is there a way that I can configure my Flex 4 project to include the JavaScript portion of the SWFAddress library? I have the AS included no problem, but in order to test its functionality, I have to open `Main.html` and include `swfaddress.js` each time I compile the Flex project, which is a tad tiring.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes you wish to persist upon build should be implemented in the html template:

[image]

By updating `index.template.html` and items within the `html-template` folder, your published html will contain the updates.